I don't understand what's happening in my code
I'm making a game with Libgdx, currently implementing terrain generation. Here is the code:
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    ScreenUtils.clear(Color.BLACK);
    camera.update();
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    Project5.INSTANCE.landTiles.forEach(landTile -> {
        spriteBatch.draw(landTile.texture,landTile.x,landTile.y);
    });
    spriteBatch.end();
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Line);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GOLDENROD);
    shapeRenderer.circle(player.x,player.y,32);
    shapeRenderer.end();

    int speed=1000;
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W))
    {
        player.y+=delta*speed;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S))
    {
        player.y-=delta*speed;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A))
    {
        player.x-=delta*speed;
    }
    if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D))
    {
        player.x+=delta*speed;
    }
    camera.position.set(player.x,player.y,0);
    Vector2 cameraPosition=new Vector2(MathUtils.round(camera.position.x/Project5.chunkSize/64),MathUtils.round(camera.position.y/Project5.chunkSize/64));
    generateChunk(cameraPosition);
    generateChunk(cameraPosition.sub(1,1));
    System.out.println(Project5.INSTANCE.generatedChunks.size());
}

private void generateChunk(Vector2 cameraPosition) {
    ArrayList<Vector2> generatedChunks= Project5.INSTANCE.generatedChunks;
    if(!generatedChunks.contains(cameraPosition))
    {
        generatedChunks.add(cameraPosition);
        float nextX= cameraPosition.x*Project5.chunkSize;
        float nextY= cameraPosition.y*Project5.chunkSize;
        for (float x =nextX; x <nextX +Project5.chunkSize; x++) {
            for (float y=nextY;y<nextY+Project5.chunkSize; y++) {
                LandTile landTile = new LandTile(Project5.INSTANCE.water, (int) ((x-Project5.chunkSize/2) * 64), (int) (y-Project5.chunkSize/2)*64);
                Project5.INSTANCE.landTiles.add(landTile);
            }
        }
    }
}

For some reason second 'generateChunk' call keeps adding the same vector. Here's what debugger is showing:

It shows that it's adding vector 0,0, but generatedChunks contains only vectors -1,-1. Am I blind? This seems wrong.

It is because you add the same instance of Vector2 over and over.
This, cameraPosition.sub(1,1) does not return a new Vector2, it just updates the existing cameraPosition.
Try changing
Vector2 cameraPosition=new Vector2(MathUtils.round(camera.position.x/Project5.chunkSize/64),MathUtils.round(camera.position.y/Project5.chunkSize/64));
generateChunk(cameraPosition);
generateChunk(cameraPosition.sub(1,1));

to
Vector2 cameraPosition=new Vector2(MathUtils.round(camera.position.x/Project5.chunkSize/64),MathUtils.round(camera.position.y/Project5.chunkSize/64));
generateChunk(cameraPosition);
generateChunk(new Vector2(cameraPosition.sub(1,1)));

